# Liquibase Maven Plugin Number Format Exception

Tags: maven, mariadb, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I'm trying to generate a Database Changelog File from existing MariaDB Database, using the Liquibase Maven Plugin but the maven goal is throwing the following error:

```
Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NULL"
```

The following configuration is set in pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <driver>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/testing</url>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    <databaseChangeLogTableName>DATABASECHANGELOG</databaseChangeLogTableName>
    <databaseChangeLogLockTableName>DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK</databaseChangeLogLockTableName>
    <outputChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml</outputChangeLogFile>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing some property or is there something else done wrong?

Comment: Could you please edit your post and include the complete exception stacktrace?

Comment: Unfortunately this is the complete exception that is given by maven in intelliJ. I tried adding the Debug Parameter but that did not result in more information.